# Using a computed column with JSON

Tags: json, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I am trying to make a computed column on data returned via JSON. I cannot get it to work. I either get a `NAN` value or it says the column does not exist.

javascript:

```
function commissionsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.commissions = ko.observableArray();
    ko.applyBindings(self, $("#commissions").get(0));

    function LoadcommissionsFromServer() {
        $.post(
            '/commissions/data',
            function (data) {
                var results = ko.observableArray();
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, results);
                for (var i = 0; i < results().length; i++) {
                    self.commissions.push(results()[i]);
                };
            },
            'json'
        )
    }

    LoadcommissionsFromServer();

    self.ComissionAmount = ko.computed(
        function () {
            return this.CommissionableAmount * this.Rate * this.Modifier;
        });
    return self;
}

var viewModel = commissionsViewModel();
```

What I am trying to accomplish is for it to recalculate the CommissionAmount after I change the modifier or rate.

**EDIT**

If I manually map the fields I get the `NaN`

```
function Commission(data) {
    this.Status = ko.observable(data.Status);
    this.OriginalCommissionCode = ko.observable(data.OriginalCommissionCode);
    this.NewCommissionCode = ko.observable(data.NewCommissionCode);
    this.InvoiceNumber = ko.observable(data.InvoiceNumber);
    this.CustomerID = ko.observable(data.CustomerID);
    this.CommissionableAmount = ko.observable(data.CommissionableAmount);
    this.Modifier = ko.observable(data.Modifier);
    this.Rate = ko.observable(data.Rate);
    this.SalesAmount = ko.observable(data.SalesAmount);
    this.NonSalesAmount = ko.observable(data.NonSalesAmount);
    this.CommissionAmount = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.CommissionableAmount * this.Rate * this.Modifier;
    });
}
function commissionsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.commissions = ko.observableArray();
    $.post(
        '/commissions/data',
        function (allData) {
            var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Commission(item) });
            self.commissions(mappedTasks);
        },
        'json'
    );
}
ko.applyBindings(new commissionsViewModel());
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/172496)

Comment: I edited the post to remove the HTML. Really, i just need to figure out why the ko.computed is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I assume Rate and Modifier are observables (You didn't provide their declaration) so you need to use the this.Rate() and this.Modififer() notations. They are functions, not properties.

Comment: Rate and Modifier are observables returned with JSON but modifier can be changed after the initial value is set. I am using ko.mapping to map the fields from the JSON.

Comment: Also, when I do that I get an error that those functions do not exist.